# Need a Macro to select specific cell from different works book in msexcel 2003

Tags: excel, vba

I need help in creating a macro;
in selecting specific cell from different works books

For Instance I have a workbook1 
and specific cell in workbook2 say "B35" and have figure 12 
likewise in workbook3 say "B35" and figure 42
and Workbook4 say "B35" and figure 53

I need all of them in Workbook1

as WB2 - B35 = 12, WB 3 = 42 so on...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Don't understand what this has to do with sql or mysql?

Comment: @PaulStock: you're right. i edited the tags of the question

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I really understood your question.

Here is the way in VBA to refer to a Range on different workbooks / worksheets:

```
Workbooks("myWB.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C10")
```

You can also use objects:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim cell as Range
Set wb = Activeworkbook 'or Workboks("myWB.xls")
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set cell = ws.Range("C10") 'or ws.["C10"]
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139976%28v=office.10%29.aspx) for more information

Answer (score 0):

I guess figure you mean the cell value right ? I have did addition, as you said you need all of them in one . Im not sure which operation you want to perform.

```
dim wb1 as excel.workbook
dim wb2 as excel.workbook
dim wb3 as excel.worbook
set wb1 = "work_book_name" 'probably where you want all your values
set wb2 = "secon_work_book" 'probable the second workbook 
set wb3 = "third_work_book"  ' probably another workbook  name
wb1.sheets("sheet_name").cells(35,"B").value= wb2.sheets("sheet_name").cells(35,"b").value + wb3.sheets("sheet_name").cells(35,"B").value
```

you can even set sheets as

```
dim sh1 as excel.worksheet \\ set as the worksheet
set sh1 = "sheet_name"
```

You can set

```
  set wb1=thisworkbook ' it refers to that workbook where macro is resided.
```

I will give you small example

Suppose your

```
  workbook name is tester.xls \I mean excel file name and your sheet name is test

  dim wb1 as excel.workbook
  dim sh1 as excel.worksheet
  set wb1 = "tester"
  set sh1 = "test"
  wb1.sh1.range("A1").value = 42 ' now it has 42 in its cell
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about copying values between workbooks.  You just need to assign the value of one cell to another cell:

```
workbooks(2).Sheets(3).Range("b4") = workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Range("a1")
```

This will loop through all active workbooks to get the value at "B35".
Each value is copied to a new row on the sheet you have active at the time you run the macro.

```
Sub getVals()

    Dim s As Worksheet
    Set s = ActiveSheet ' Change this to where ever you want to copy the values to
    i = 1

    ' loop through all open workbooks
    For Each wkbk In Workbooks
        ' copy the name of the workbook
            s.Cells(i, 1) = wkbk.Name
        ' copy value from "B35" to the first workbook
            s.Cells(i, 2) = wkbk.Sheets(1).Range("B35")
        ' increment i so that it points to the next row
            i = i + 1
    Next

End Sub
```